# 301 redirect в wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

Не могу разобраться как настроить 301 редирект на wordpress. Во первых где должен лежать пользовательский файл .htaccess (в корне сайта или в папке с темой или может еще гдето), а во вторых, пробовал разные варианты расположения файла, но все равно не срабатывает редирект вида:

```
Redirect 301 https://site/123/page https://site/321/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Файл `.htaccess` должен находиться в корне **запрашиваемого** сайта.
2. Директивы редиректа пишутся до секции `#Begin WordPress`.
3. Ошибка в синтаксисе  редиректа. Правильно так: `Redirect 301 /123/page https://new-site/123/`

*ЗЫ. Для смена домена этого не достаточно.*